Ying Yang 12x12 - Colombian Sudoku
Here is this week's Sudoku, my latest creation. It's a Colombian Sudoku that, despite its size, presents an extreme level of difficulty. Remember the rules: you must fill in the Sudoku on the left while also using the grid on the right, keeping in mind that the number of dots indicates how many numbers match in that row and/or column. Good luck!


What is the significance of the of the shape? Where the ALL-game rules appear?

It seems you assume that without the right grid there are more than one solution. Also, why you call this Colombian - there are no diagonals!

@Moti Without the right grid there are thousands of solutions.

Hello @Moti. Colombian sudoku puzzles work with an additional grid with clues. You can see the other sudoku puzzles I have published. There you will understand better how they work.

Via integer linear programming, using the formulation described in my answer https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/128031/65277:

 \begin{matrix}3 & 7 & 10 & 11 & 4 & 8 & 2 & 5 & 9 & 1 & 6 & 12\\5 & 12 & 8 & 9 & 6 & 7 & 1 & 3 & 2 & 11 & 10 & 4\\6 & 4 & 2 & 1 & 11 & 12 & 10 & 9 & 8 & 3 & 7 & 5\\8 & 2 & 11 & 10 & 3 & 4 & 9 & 1 & 7 & 12 & 5 & 6\\7 & 5 & 4 & 12 & 2 & 11 & 6 & 8 & 10 & 9 & 3 & 1\\1 & 6 & 9 & 3 & 7 & 10 & 5 & 12 & 4 & 2 & 11 & 8\\12 & 9 & 6 & 4 & 5 & 1 & 11 & 7 & 3 & 10 & 8 & 2\\11 & 3 & 1 & 7 & 8 & 2 & 4 & 10 & 5 & 6 & 12 & 9\\10 & 8 & 5 & 2 & 9 & 3 & 12 & 6 & 1 & 7 & 4 & 11\\9 & 10 & 12 & 8 & 1 & 6 &3 & 4 & 11 & 5 & 2 & 7\\2 & 1 & 7 & 6 & 10 & 5 & 8 & 11 & 12 & 4 & 9 & 3\\4 & 11 & 3 & 5 & 12 & 9 & 7 & 2 & 6 & 8 & 1 & 10\\\end{matrix}

